# Wildcard in cmd files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I am faced with a situation where I need to delete one file in all users directories

E.g.

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\deleteme.txt
C:\Users\User2\Desktop\deleteme.txt
C:\Users\User3\Desktop\deleteme.txt
```

I am in need of a command that will treat the users directory as a wildcard, so I don't need to specify anything.

I have tried:

```
C:\Users\*\Desktop\deleteme.txt
```

Which doesn't work :(

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: sorry I have tried: C:\Users\*\Desktop\deleteme.txt (For some reason this editor wont let me insert double backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try iterating the needed folders :

```
for %%X in (C:\Users\User1 C:\Users\User2 C:\Users\User3) do (del %%X\Desktop\deleteme.txt )
```

or

```
for /d %%X in (C:\Users\*) do (del %%X\Desktop\deleteme.txt )
```

There is a good article
[Iterating with "For"](http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-iterating.htm)

**UPDATE**
In this way :

```
for /d %%A in (C:\Users\*) do for /d %%B in (%%A\*) do echo %%B
```

You can list all subdirectories in all user's folders.

Comment: The problem is though, that I do not know the usernames beforehand, hence a wildcard is necessary, so there is no way of doing it then? :(

Comment: Sorry I didnt read you answer properly. Thank you very much, you have saved me a lot of time :) Thanks!

Comment: @James: You can accept a solution you consider correct and upvote solutions you consider helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didnt realize you could do that, while the questions is open how would you do something like: (del %%X\Desktop\\Folder\%%X\deleteme.txt ) ?

Comment: for /d %%X %%Y in (C:\Users\*) do (del %%X\Desktop\%%Y\deleteme.txt )    ??

Comment: Look please at the updated answer. There is an example with nested loops.

Answer (score -2):

> C:\Users*\Desktop\deleteme.txt

I thought there might be a backslash missing after `C:\Users`, but it isn't. It's a problem of the syntax here, as I just noticed. A backslash in front of an astrisk is omitted.

If a batch file proves unsufficient and you are working on Windows 7 only, you could switch to [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)

Comment: To get the missing backslash, you have to use double backslashs: `C:\Users\\*\`

Comment: Unfortunateley its a mixture of platforms (XP+), so there is no way of achieving what I would like to do in cmd?

Comment: The missing backslash was just a formatting problem and is solved by now. See the other answer, though; this is trivial with `cmd`.